# Connections pool (database or other service) across cluster of containers

Tags: database, containers, microservices, connection-pooling

I expected this to be a common problem but couldn't find a definitive answer.
The scenario is the following:

- You have a micro-service application deployed in containers. Each micro-service is deployed in its own container and can be vertically/horizontally scaled independently from the others.
- One of these micro-service needs to connect to a service like a database. You use your preferred client library to connect to that specific database, using a connections pool inside the micro-service application.
- Your application is elastic, meaning it should scale in and out basing on some workload metrics, deploying/removing containers if required.

Now here is the problem. Your database can accept only a limited number of connections, let's say 100. Say also that your micro-service requiring database connection has a connections pool with a max limit of 10. This means that effectively your micro-service can't horizontally scale out beyond 10 containers, otherwise you can can go above the max number of connections supported by the database.
Ideally you would like to scale out the service independently from the database connections limit, having some sort of stateful pool service across the cluster of containers that is aware of the total number of connections currently active.

What are possible solutions to the above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is the database that you use but for example in postgresql, there is a "pool service" as you say, called pgbouncer,https://www.pgbouncer.org/ that acts as a global connection pool for all services or instances that requires connection to de database.

You deploy it as a separate service and you configure it to connect to your postgresql instance and also configure the number of connections available if they can be reused among services.. etc. Then you have to connect you microservices to this pgbouncer and this way you are sure that you won't overload the database no matter the number of instances of the microservice...

If you are not using postgresql I am pretty sure that other databases have similar solutions